# Does the AXA-Schengen Europe Travel insurance satisfy the German consulate's insurance requirements?

Tags: schengen, insurance

I just purchased AXA-Schengen Europe Travel insurance, and am applying to the German Consulate for my Schengen visa. [These](http://www.germany.info/contentblob/4408750/Daten/5015918/Medical_Health_Insurance_PDF.pdf) are the requirements as stated by the German Consulate for the insurance required. My certificate covers everything, except it looks like the coverage is not split equally across all benefits. It doesn't seem very clear to me.

Does anyone know if this insurance is okay?

Comment: Can you copy the relevant terms of your contract or point to some online source? [Is this your insurance](https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/coverage)?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure exactly where the consulate found this rule about coverage having to be “split equally” between benefits but I assume it's to prevent people form using two unrelated insurance contracts not intended for this, which could leave them with a low coverage for one of the benefits. [AXA's terms and conditions aren't really clear on this](https://www.axa-schengen.com/subscribe/downloads/low_cost/cg_axa_schengen_low_cost_uk.pdf) but it seems that medical treatment and repatriation are both covered up to €30000.

In any case, since

1. the requirement for travel health insurance are defined in the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018) and apply to all member states (i.e. Germany is not supposed to make its own rules),
2. the [page from the German missions to the US](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/Visa__Medical__Insurance.html) explicitly lists AXA Schengen (among other insurers),
3. and [that contract is specifically intended for Schengen visa applications](https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/coverage) (and apparently used by thousands of people for this purpose)

it would seem exceedingly unlikely that it would not be appropriate to support a visa application or that the German consulate could refuse it.

Comment: Hey, this was very useful thanks. Going to purchase low-cost AXA insurance.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Canada, this page lists the details of the requirements for the travel insurance (for German Schengen Visa) (link: https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/consular-services/visa/travel-health-insurance/1308210).

One of the requirement is

> the insurance has to be provided by a Canadian or German insurance company

Hope this help Canadian residents who are applying for German visa.